# IOException when sending request right after httpclient is created

Tags: java, httpclient

I looked around and couldn't find any similar question for this though it sounds like a dummy question. The problem is I get IOException every time why sending request immediately after creating a default httpclient.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// This throws IOException
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

However it works well if I sleep some time after creating httpclient and before sending the request.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
  Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
// This works.
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

This is java 1.7 and apache httpclient 4.2.3. Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: Where are you declaring `httpPost`?